# Convert list to another list using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

The need is a little strange. I want to convert a list to a new list. For example, convert `List<Android>` to `List<AndroidWrapper>`.

class `AndroidWrapper` has two fields.

```
public class AndroidWrapper {
    private Android mAndroid;
    private String mAvatarUrl;

    public AndroidWrapper(Android android, String avatarUrl) {
        this.mAndroid = android;
        this.mAvatarUrl = avatarUrl;
    }
}
```

The field `mAvatar` is related to `mAndroid` field and it can be fetched from remote server.

```
Observable<String> fetchAvatarUrl(Android android)
```

So how can do this using `RxJava2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your list into an `Observable`, `flatMap` the dependent call onto it, create the final object type and collect it into a list:

```java
Observable.fromIterable(androids)
.flatMap(android ->
     fetchAvatarUrl(android)
     // go into a backgroud thread
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     // combine the result with the original value
     .map(url -> new AndroidWrapper(android, url))
     // limit the maximum concurrent fetch calls
     , 1
)
.toList();
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Since android has not supported Java-8 yet, can you append a non-lambda version.

Comment: Your Android Studio should be able to convert this to that format, plus you can now have lambda support: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am new to lambda, so I do need non-lambda version.

Comment: Paste in the code sample above, position on the `->`, hit ALT+ENTER and pick "Replace lambda with anonymous class". Repeat for the other `->`.

Comment: method `toList` return `Single<List<T>>`

Comment: Yes. Is that a problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166398/discussion-between-coxier-and-akarnokd).